# copying view objects

Tags: android

I have a ListView that I am populating with LinearLayouts that contain one CheckBox apiece.  The LinearLayout's are added dynamically for each object I am returning from a web service I have.
I need for a user to be able to click a done button and for the application to go through the list of CheckBox's and update a database for each checked item.  The database and the done button were a piece of cake, but obtaining a reference to or making a copy, how ever you choose to look at it, of the CheckBox thus far has stumped me for days.

my code as of now for this process looks something like this:

private ListView List = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

LinearLayout temp;
CheckBox curr;

for ( int i = 0; i< List.getChildCount(); i++) {
   temp = (LinearLayout)List.getChildAt(i);
   curr = (CheckBox)temp.getChildAt(1);
   if ( curr.isChecked() ) {
      //do stuff here
   }
}

as soon as I try and reference either the temp object or the curr object the program crashes.  So in the above code it crashes at curr.isChecked().  I discovered previously that if you forget that the CheckBox is wrapped in a LinearLayout and try to copy a LinearLayout object to a CheckBox object the program crashes, so I know the system sees the correct object to copy, even at the curr copy... however if i try to log the temp class type like this
Log.d("temp Class type", temp.getClass().toString());
the system crashes

However the following works perfectly fine...
Log.d("List Class type", List.getChildAt(i).getClass().toString());

The only thing I can come up with at this point is that I need to overload a copy construct somewhere, but I can not find anything that advises you on how to begin this or what the copy function might be called.  Even google code searches have proved fruitless for me...

I have a feeling this is just something I am looking at completely 180 degrees the wrong way and it is going to be ridiculously simple, but if there were a way to rip the emulator off the screen and throw it through the wall I would have done it by now, please help!

-David

...and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Java language works by reference, when you write Checkbox curr = [an expression of type checkbox], you are not making a copy of the Checkbox object. To help you with your issue, it would be very helpful to see the stack trace of the crash (you'll find it in the logs.)

Comment: 08-29 06:46:14.823: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1086): Shutting down VM
08-29 06:46:14.823: WARN/dalvikvm(1086): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
08-29 06:46:14.833: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at cards.pkg.Select.auditDB(Select.java:376)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at cards.pkg.Select.access$6(Select.java:335)

Comment: 08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at cards.pkg.Select$2$1.onClick(Select.java:90)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6534)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)

Comment: 08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:883)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:883)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:883)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:883)

Comment: 08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)

Comment: 08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4338)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: 08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-29 06:46:14.863: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1086):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)